# Python 2: Why is this bytestring order switched in struct.pack() and struct.unpack() methods?

Tags: python, struct, hex

In Python 2.7.5, I have an hex 0xbba1, and I want to change it in bytestring format.

```
>>> bytetoint = lambda bytestr: struct.unpack('H', bytestr)[0]
>>> hextobyte = lambda hexnum: struct.pack('H', hexnum)
>>> hextobyte(0xbba1)
'\xa1\xbb'
>>> hex(bytetoint('\xa1\xbb'))
'0xbba1'
```

Why are the first byte '\xa1' and the second byte'\xbb' switched in place?

How can I get the right bytestring from hex, or vice versa?

e.g. 0xbba1 -> '\xbb\xa1' 
'\xbb\xa1' -> 0xbba1

Comment: See the note at the top of the [`struct` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [little-endian/big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) thing. You can't really say the bytes are switched, because nothing in the `int` definition says what order the bytes representing it are laid out in.

The result you have is a perfectly usable little-endian representation. If you want to force big-endian, which may look better to a human reader, you can specify the byte order with `>`:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>H', 0xbba1)
'\xbb\xa1'
>>> hex(struct.unpack('>H', '\xbb\xa1')[0])
'0xbba1'
```

Comment: Awesome, almost exactly the same response within seconds of each other  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First read about [endianness](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) so that you understand where this problem is coming from. On a typical x86-based computer with a little-endian CPU, the correct in-memory representation of `int(0xbba1)` is the two bytes `a1 bb`, in that order.

If you really want to decode a byte string from the opposite big-endian order, see [this section of the `struct` docs](//docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

```
bytestring = `\xbb\xa1`
hex( struct.unpack('>H','\xbb\xa1')[0] )
```